# Give Title of a Fieldset a Background Color

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to make the title of fieldset have a solid background color. When I try changing color in the CSS it colors the whole fieldset box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
   <fieldset>
    <legend >Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
```

css

```
fieldset legend {background:red}
```

working sample http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/taBqH

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the legend.